# How to Render Panel control to Pdf and Excel file in Windows form

Tags: winforms, printing, pdf-generation, panel

This a Panel Control Contain Invoice Bill:

[image]

I want to make this Panel in Pdf and Excel file,but not in image format as a regular pdf file. This code is Written in Windows c#.

```
Graphics grp = panel.CreateGraphics();
Size formSize = this.ClientSize;
bitmap = new Bitmap(formSize.Width, 610, grp);
grp = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
Point panelLocation = PointToScreen(panel.Location);
grp.CopyFromScreen(panelLocation.X, panelLocation.Y, 0, 0, formSize);
printPreviewDialog1.Document = printDocument1;
printPreviewDialog1.PrintPreviewControl.Zoom = 1;
printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog();
```

but it makes screen shot and create pdf file..

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing that I know of that will take your image and create a "nice" PDF (small, searchable, zoomable) automatically.  There is just too much room for error.

You will need to use something that is report-specific or pdf-specific to create your document.  Depending on your requirements Docmosis and iText are good at this.  Docmosis lets you build your layout in a doc template so it's easier than building in code, but it will still take work specific to the report you are creating.  Please note I work for Docmosis.  If you prefer a code-approach, iText is very good.

I hope that helps.